# Groovy closure-on-collection-methods inconsistent type transformation

Tags: groovy, spock

There is strange behaviour in Groovy. Have a look on two examples below:

```
def list = [[BigDecimal.ONE]]
list.each {
    println it.class
}
```

prints:

> class java.util.ArrayList

and

```
def list = [[BigDecimal.ONE]]
list.each { BigDecimal it ->
    println it.class
}
```

prints:

> class java.math.BigDecimal

The only difference in the examples is that the 2nd one has a argument type for the closure specified. But this doesn't explain why and how the inner `List` is being transformed to `BigDecimal`. I would rather expect `ClassCastException`. Moreover this behaviour is inconsistent, as if there are more elements in the inner list it fails with `MissingMethodException`.

We've found that this magic type conversion happens in [`ClosureMetaClass`](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/GROOVY_2_3_6/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/metaclass/ClosureMetaClass.java#L256) (line: 256)

Is it a designed behaviour or a bug?

**EDIT:**
I came across the above issue while trying to stub a method with Spock. The method takes `Collection` as a parameter. Consider another example:

```
def 'stub a method with collection as argument'() {
    given:
    def input = [1, 2, 3]
    def capturedArgument
    List listStub = Stub()
    listStub.addAll(input) >> {
        capturedArgument = it
    }

    when:
    listStub.addAll(input)

    then:
    input.class == capturedArgument.class
}
```

It fails with:

```
Condition not satisfied:

input.class == capturedArgument.class
|     |     |  |                |
|     |     |  [[1, 2, 3]]      class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList
|     |     false
|     class java.util.ArrayList
[1, 2, 3]
```

The problem is that argument `it` comes as `List` embedded in another `List` into the method stubbing closure. WTF?

The only way to overcome this is stubbing method with **the exact same argument type as input type** like

```
listStub.addAll(input) >> { ArrayList it ->
```

...then the test passes. It's a real no-go as I need to use interface as the stub argument type, not a specific implementation. And when it's declared like

```
listStub.addAll(input) >> { List it ->
```

or

```
listStub.addAll(input) >> { Collection it ->
```

...it fails the same way as without type because *input* list gets embedded in another list.

Here's [live example](https://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5651442522128384) if you like to run and play with it

Comment: The type of capturedArguments is: `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` because of this piece of code in `DefaultGroovyMethods.java`: `public static <T> boolean addAll(Collection<T> self, T[] items) {
        return self.addAll(Arrays.asList(items));
    }`. It all works correct. If You specify the argument explicitly it gets converted automatically and exceptions isn't thrown. See: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java

Comment: In a Spock mock response, `it` or a single untyped closure parameter will contain the method's argument list. If typed closure parameters are used instead, Spock will try to destructure according to Groovy semantics. See http://docs.spockframework.org.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I understand now why my input list is embedded in another list for untyped Spock mock response argument. But why the same happens even if argument is typed but with parent class or interface? I'll have a look in docs again of course, but if you could tell a few words more about that would be awesome. Here's example what I'm asking about https://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5723151296102400 This way there's need of stubbing the same method multiple times for let say: LinkedList, ArrayList, Set, etc... It doesn't really look well, even CodeNarc complains with _ImplementationAsType_

Comment: Destructuring will (only) kick in if the closure argument cannot be passed as-is as per the closure's declared parameter type(s). (In contrary to what I've said before, *all* of this is under Groovy's control and therefore follows standard Groovy semantics. Spock just calls the closure with a single argument of type `List`, representing the stubbed invocation's argument list.) In other words, when stubbing a method with a single parameter of type `Iterable`, `Collection`, or `List`, you'll have to destructure manually (`>> { args -> args[0] }` or `>> { it[0] }`).

Comment: ^^^ This last sentence would be nice to have in the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

groovy destructures the items provided to the closure (best example is each on `Map`, where key and value are passed).  so it is consistent on consistent use:

```
[[BigDecimal.ONE],[BigDecimal.ONE]].each{ BigDecimal it -> println it } 
//=> 1
//=> 1
[[BigDecimal.ONE, BigDecimal.ONE]].each{ a, b -> println "$a and $b" }
//=> 1 and 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I can see the reason for such behaviour with `Map` and I'm using it quite often. However with `Collection` it may lead to unexpected app behaviour. Anyway, can you please have a look under 'edit' section in my original question and explain this mystery?

Comment: sorry i can't help with the spock problem and imho this would even make a new question (where e.g. Peter would have a chance to provide a full blown answer)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure is it the same issue or not. Actually it's not exactly the same but they are related.
I was considering to ask it as a new question and probably I should've.